# Erro ao setar cookies com data de expiração com javascript "Quando terminar a sessão de navegação"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```js
function createCookie(name,value) {

    name = "testeeee";
    value = "conteudo do teseeee";
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(720*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toLocaleString();

    alert(date.toLocaleString());
    alert(name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/");
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }
```

Porém no navegador aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tento de todas as forma definir a data final dele para expirar, mas só da nisso no navegador.

Comment: Você quer que o cookie fique até quanto tempo? Pelo meu calculo você quer 12h ou estou errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Data de expiração do cookie deve ser GMT. Utilize a função 'toGMTString' conforme abaixo:

```js
function createCookie(name,value) {

    name = "testeeee";
    value = "conteudo do teseeee";
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(720*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

    alert(date.toLocaleString());
    alert(name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/");
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: Dnada amigo. ;)